# Is there a way to save a USB device so that re-enumeration can be prevented after replugging?

Tags: c++, windows, usb

First of all, we are working with a 3rd party software that ties itself to a USB device. When this USB device is disconnected and reconnected, the software cannot communicate with the device <s>will stop working</s> until the program is restarted. i.e. It only detects the USB device on startup.

Windows is able to see the device, but goes through the full detection/driver installation procedure every time it is reconnected, even if it is reconnected to the same USB port.

The difficulty here is that we have no way of modifying the third party software to poll for the appropriate USB device after the device is unplugged.

As such, we would like to ask if anyone has knowledge on how to go about writing a c++ program to save a USB state/register, prevent Windows from re-enumerating the USB port upon re-connection, and restoring the saved state/register. If so, we would appreciate some guidance in this endeavor. Naturally, we are open to other approaches to solving this issue.

Comment: Apparently the software _does_ notice the disconnect, at any moment. Wouldn't it be easier to hack around this?

Comment: My apologies, I worded the question wrongly. The application itself does not stop working in the sense that it crashes. But due to the nature of its operation, it takes input via the USB device and processes it. When the USB device is removed, the application ceases being useful, although it is still running.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do this at application level. USB is managed by drivers. Furthermore, while the details of USB devices are managed by specific drivers, the basics (such as enumeration) are handled by the standard Windows USB driver. That's logical: Windows has to enumerate the device first to determine its Vendor ID and Product ID, which then determines the specific driver to load.

As for the full reinstallation on every reinsertion, that suggests a violation of the USB spec by the device or the Windows API by the driver. My first guess would be that the device doesn't have a proper serial number.

Comment: Thanks. However, we have no control over the 3rd party program or the device drivers in question. Is there perhaps a way that a USB port can be "suspended" and disconnected without unloading the drivers?

Comment: Similar happens to me with a device from a major manufacturer (Logitech headset, as it happens), so I daresay it's not _necessarily_ Soya Bean' device that is missing something, but quite possibly the Windows USB driver being a particularly dumb implementation. I've had the same, identical device plugged into 4 ports and 4 driver installations...

Comment: @Damon: As someone who actually works for such a major manufacturer (but not Logitech) I can say from experience that major manufacturers are just as likely to violate USB specs, as long as the product works. If your headphone works with 4 driver installations, then what's the manufacturers problem?